# Set InAppBrowser or Themeable Browser height to show app's bottom tabs

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I've searched about this around ionic forums, stackoverflow, etc., but I still haven't found an answer.

I'm creating an ionic 4 app with an inappbrowser inside and I want it to be like a part of the app with the bottom tabs showing.

Others suggested to use iframe but I'm not sure if that's good since they're also saying that it has issues uploading to the apple app store.

**My folder structure:**

- Tabs Folder
- Page 1 Folder (Where the inappbrowser is located)
- Page 2 Folder (This page shows with the tabs and has no problem)

**Here's the code in the page 1 folder:**

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  const browser = this.iab.create(url, '_blank', {location:'no', 
  footer:'no', zoom:'no', usewkwebview:'yes', toolbar:'no'});
});
```

**and Here's the routes of the tab folder:**

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'tabs',
  component: TabsPage,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'page1',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          loadChildren: '../page1/page1.module#page1Module'
        }
      ]
    }
```

**I understand that inAppBrowser covers all the parts of the app** and has the absolute position, so the solution I'm thinking is to just set a height for the inAppBrowser so that it will not cover the bottom tabs, but is that possible?

Comment: Can show few code how you used inappbrowser in tabs

Comment: alright, I added the codes and structure

Comment: @MarcelWade Can you please let me know whether you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I used React Native instead.
As [React Native webview](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview) is not in a different layer, and can be inserted on any part of the app.